# Using GET method on mysql WHERE clause on datatable plugin not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am using datatable (https://datatables.net/) plugin to generate the data.
All the datas are coming from the `enrollments` database table.

I could not able to find the where the problem. When i try to use `GET` method to get the variable to use on `WHERE` Clause, i get an error. Let me know if you need further code.

`file1: enrollment_select_statement.php`

```php
$sqlEnrollments = "SELECT e.enrollment_id, e.studentid, e.joiningdate, e.notes, e.termyearid,
    s.student_id, s.firstname, s.lastname, s.section, s.standard AS studentstandard, s.status,
    c.course_id, c.subject AS coursesubject, c.standard AS coursestandard, c.termyearid AS coursetermyearid,
    b.name AS batchname,
    t.total, t.name AS termname, t.startingdate, t.endingdate,
    sc.name AS schoolname,
    ty.currentyear, ty.nextyear,
    tyc.currentyear AS currentyearforcourse, tyc.nextyear AS nextyearforcourse
FROM enrollments e
    LEFT JOIN students s    ON e.studentid = s.student_id
    LEFT JOIN courses c     ON e.courseid = c.course_id
    LEFT JOIN batches b     ON e.batchid = b.batch_id
    LEFT JOIN terms t       ON e.termid = t.term_id
    LEFT JOIN termyears ty  ON e.termyearid = ty.termyear_id
    LEFT JOIN schools sc    ON s.schoolid = sc.school_id
    LEFT JOIN termyears tyc ON c.termyearid = tyc.termyear_id";
$resultEnrollments = mysqli_query($con, $sqlEnrollments);
```

The above file is included in this page.

`file2: enrollment_data.php`

```php
include 'database/db_enrollment/enrollment_select_statement.php';

$data = [];
foreach ($resultEnrollments as $row) {
    $enrollmentNotes = $row['notes'];
    $enrollmentJoiningDate = $row['joiningdate'];
    ...

    $data[] = [
        'term_name_year' => "<small>".$termName."<br> <span class='text-muted'>".termYearFunction($currentYear, $nextYear)."</span></small>",
        'student_name' => $studentFirstname.' '.$studentLastname.'<br>'.$stdSecCondition,
        ...
    ];
}

echo json_encode(array('data' => $data));
```

Here's the final file `js`

`file3: database_for_enrollment.js`

```php
$('#enrollmentTableForDataTable').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: 'enrollment_data.php'
    },
    columns:
    [
        { data: 'term_name_year' },
        { data: 'student_name' },
        { data: 'course_subject_standard' },
        { data: 'enrollment_joiningdate' },
        { data: 'notes' },
        { data: 'status' },
        { "mData": function (data, type, dataToSet) {
            var lnk = data.edit_hreflink;
            var hrefO = "<a href='" + lnk + "'>";
            var hrefC = "</a>";
            return hrefO + 'Edit' + hrefC;
        }},
    ],
});
```

Let me explain

**Option 1: Works**
Using an `$id = 1`

```
$id = 1

$sqlEnrollments = "SELECT e.enrollment_id, e.studentid, e.joiningdate, e.notes, e.termyearid,
    ...
    WHERE e.termyearid = $id";
```

**Option 2: Works**
Using it from the `SELECT` statement but the number is hard-coded for `WHERE` clause

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM termyears WHERE termyear_id = 1";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$id = $row['termyear_id'];

$sqlEnrollments = "SELECT e.enrollment_id, e.studentid, e.joiningdate, e.notes, e.termyearid,
    ...
    WHERE e.termyearid = $id";
```

**Option 3: Doesn't Work**
Adding the `$URLtyId` variable from the `$_GET`

```
$URLtyId = '';
if( isset( $_GET['tyId']) ) {
    $URLtyId = $_GET['tyId'];
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM termyears WHERE termyear_id = $URLtyId";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$id = $row['termyear_id'];

$sqlEnrollments = "SELECT e.enrollment_id, e.studentid, e.joiningdate, e.notes, e.termyearid,
    ...
    WHERE e.termyearid = $id";
```

When i try to include the `WHERE` clause from `GET` method. i get this error.

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in localhost\enrollment_data.php on line 15
{"data":[]}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put your request in your condition : (for example)

```
if( isset( $_GET['tyId']) ) {
    $URLtyId = $_GET['tyId'];
    $sql = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM termyears WHERE id = $URLtyId");
    $reqRow = $sql->rowCount();
    if($reqRow == 1){
      while($f = $sql->fetch()){
        echo $f["name"]
        //your database row
      }
     }
}
```

Comment: I get the same error. I am not getting any error from your code, but it is same error i mentioned above. Just to clarify a little, I need to use only the `tyId` that should do. Because i was getting error from the `GET` method. i made the SELECT statement as a workaround.

Comment: The `$id` is working if i `echo` but it is not working inside the `WHERE` clause.